# Trail bottle depot. What does word 'trail' stand for?

Tags: meaning, canadian-english

I often see signs on buildings in Canada 'Trail Bottle Depot'.

What does word 'trail' stand for in this case?

Comment: The trail bottle is the modern canteen, a covered **travel** mug. Canada recycles.

Comment: _Finished with that can of pop? Do not throw it in the garbage can! Get cash now for your beverage containers by bringing them to Trail Bottle Depot – your bottle recycling centre in Calgary and surrounding areas. You give us your empty beverage containers and we give you a cash refund. It is that simple. Then we recycle all the returned containers we collect. So, you are also playing a part in keeping our community clean. For any further queries, you can reach us through phone or email._

Comment: [The Trail Bottle Depot in Trail, BC](https://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/WMFDZY_RC_Glasstop_Bottle_Depot_Trail_British_Columbia)?